# Question about Majorana spinor's property

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spinors, majorana-fermions, dirac-matrices

I am reading the BBS, Exercise 5.1

> This exercise is nothing but showing that two Majorana spinors $\Theta_1$ and $\Theta_2$
>   \begin{align}
> \bar{\Theta}_1 \Gamma_{\mu} \Theta_2 = -\bar{\Theta}_2 \Gamma_\mu \Theta_1
> \end{align}
>   In BBS, there are solutions for exercise that I did not fully understand.

First I know the 
\begin{align}
\bar{\Theta}_1 \Gamma_{\mu} \Theta_2 = \Theta_1^{\dagger} \Gamma_0 \Gamma_{\mu} \Theta_2 = \Theta_1^T C \Gamma_{\mu} \Theta_2
\end{align}
They said that this can be written in the form 
\begin{align}
- \Theta_2^T \Gamma_{\mu}^T C^T \Theta_1 = - \Theta_2^T C \Gamma_{\mu}\Theta_1 = -\bar{\Theta}_2 \Gamma_{\mu} \Theta_1
\end{align}
What i don't understand is why

\begin{align}
\Theta_1^T C \Gamma_{\mu} \Theta_2=- \Theta_2^T \Gamma_{\mu}^T C^T \Theta_1
\end{align}

cf)
I know that for the gamma matrix for Majorana spinor follows 
\begin{align}
C\Gamma_{\mu}= - \Gamma_\mu^T C 
\end{align}
which is related with above equation.

References:

[BBS] Becker, Becker, Schwarz, "String theory and M-theory: A modern Introduction".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation you ask about is just a reshuffling of the components. Writing out the indices we have
$$
\Theta_1^T C \, \Gamma_{\mu} \Theta_2 
=
(\Theta_1^T)_a C_{ab} \, (\Gamma_{\mu})_{bc} (\Theta_2)_c
=
- (\Theta_2)_c (\Gamma_{\mu})_{bc}  C_{ab} (\Theta_1^T)_a
=
- (\Theta_2^T)_c (\Gamma_{\mu}^T)_{cb} (C^T)_{ba} (\Theta_1)_a
$$
where the minus sign in the second step came from switching the order of the two fermions.
Removing the indices again we then have
$$
\Theta_1^T C \, \Gamma_{\mu} \Theta_2 
=
- \Theta_2^T\Gamma_{\mu}^T C^T \Theta_1
$$
which is what you asked about.

Depending on your spinor conventions you might need to be more careful about the placement of the spinor indices than I was above, but the general idea should be the same.

Comment: Thank your for answer!. It helps me a lot. Now i totally understand!. From your answer, I finally derive the other useful spinors identities!